# how to pass " ' " using append jQuery

Tags: jquery, append

Hi friends I am doing a simple thing just append input box by clicking problem is  in my input box am using `placeholder="Enter Friend's Email ID"` in this line the word "Friend's" is not coming as its showing its missed `'` after appending plz check my code below or you can check [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4YVbB/)

**HTML**

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="emailTable">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan="2">
                    <strong>Share this greeting with your friend</strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="417" align="right">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Friend's Email ID" class="mail" id="SendMail" name="SendMail">
                </td>
                <td width="156">  <div class="addRow">Add more Recipients</div></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var row = "'"
    alert(row)
   $('.addRow').click(function(){
       $('#emailTable').append("<tr><td  align='right'><input type='text' placeholder='Enter Friends Email ID"+row+"s' class='mail' id='SendMail' name='SendMail'></td><td></td></tr>")
       })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the code to this and it should work:

```
   $('.addRow').click(function(){
       $('#emailTable tbody').append("<tr><td  align='right'><input type='text' placeholder=\"Enter Friend's Email ID\" class='mail' id='SendMail' name='SendMail'></td><td></td></tr>");
   });
```

Note the placehoder now uses escaped (`\"`) double quotes instead so the single quote inside does not close it early.

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/4YVbB/3/

I also changed the text to match what is already in the HTML (Enter Friend's Email ID)

Comment: that works, but in this case i would replace all the atributes quotes to double quotes

Answer (score 3):

you have to escape it like so :

```
placeholder='Enter Friends Email ID\'s'
```

that way you don't need the row var either

since the above code did not do the trick (read comments):
EDIT: replacing single with double quotes

```
$('#emailTable').append("<tr><td  align=\"right\"><input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Enter Friends Email ID's\" class=\"mail\" id=\"SendMail\" name=\"SendMail\"></td><td></td></tr>")
```

Comment: hi Gret B i used this in my code nothing happend .. Will you plz share fiddle here

Comment: I edited this answer with a second code example. this one i tested on your fiddle an worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Your codeline

```
  $('#emailTable').append(
  "<tr><td  align='right'><input type='text' placeholder='Enter Friends Email ID"
   + row + "s' class='mail' id='SendMail' name='SendMail'></td><td></td></tr>");
```

Will be seperated into 3 interpreter-steps.

1. `stringParam = "<tr><td  align='right'><input type='text' placeholder='Enter Friends Email ID"
   <ul>
   <li>row + "s' class='mail' id='SendMail' name='SendMail'></td><td></td></tr>";`
2. `table = $('#emailTable');`
3. `table.append(stringParam);` <-- here jquery throws the Exception.

In step 1 stringParam becomes a invalid html-string. But its a String anyway, so there is no Problem to the interpreter.

In step 3 there is the Problem, because the `stringParam` contains invalid html.

Think about templating should do the trick.
http://sideroad.secret.jp/plugins/jQueryRender/
So you can write pure HTML and quotas are automatically escaped. This way you are meta-type-save.